# Statsmodels Clustered Logit Model With Robust Standard Errors

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels, stderr

I have the following dataframe:

```py
df.head()

        id    case   volfluid   map   rr    o2    fluid
1044    36    3      3.0        1.0   3.0   2.0   0.0
1045    37    3      2.0        3.0   1.0   2.0   1.0
1046    38    3      3.0        2.0   2.0   1.0   0.0
1047    36    4      2.0        3.0   1.0   3.0   1.0
1048    37    4      1.0        1.0   3.0   3.0   1.0
.
.
.
```

I want to run a logistic regression model clustered on `id` and with robust standard errors. Here is what I have for the equation

```py
smf.logit('''fluid ~ C(volfluid) + C(map, Treatment(reference = 3.0)) + 
             C(o2, Treatment(reference = 3.0)) + C(rr) + 
             C(case, Treatment(reference = 4))''',
             data = df).fit(cov_type='cluster', cov_kwds={'groups': df['id']})
```

I'm not sure if this accomplishes both the clustering, and the robust std. errors. I understand that setting `cov_type = 'hc0'` provides robust std. errors, but if I do that can I still cluster on `id`? And do I need to do that, or are clustered standard errors inherently robust?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cluster robust standard errors are also heteroscedasticity robust (HC). A HC cov_types do not take any correlation into account.

Related aside: Using GEE with independence correlation has the same underlying model as Logit but has the option of bias-reduced cluster robust standard errors (similar so CR3, the HC3 analogue for cluster correlations)

Comment: Thank you for the response @Josef. So do I have my bases covered with my approach, or should I use the GEE with independence correlation? Fyi, the clusters are on id and they are duplicated once across Cases 3 and 4. In other words, do I need to be taking correlation into account?

Comment: Logit with cluster robust standard errors corrects for the within cluster correlation and so is fine for the use case. However, cov_type cluster corresponds to HC0 or HC1 in terms of small sample corrections. In small samples HC3 is recommended over HC1 and HC2 and CR3 would be better than CR0 or CR1 if the number of groups is small. (Wald test with small number of clusters in general overrejects null hypotheses, while score_test underrejects)

Comment: Okay, got it. My total N is around 1000 and there are two groups. So it possible to set cov_type to HC3 and also select which variable to cluster on, or are those mutually exclusive?

Comment: No, because HC would not know what to do with cluster id. It only corrects for heteroscedasticity. (It's supposed to raise an exception if there is an unused `cov_kwd`)

Comment: Ok, understood. So in this case, if I need to make sure I am clustering on `id` with robust std. errors, will my results be significantly affected if I don't take into account your points about correlation and sample size, or will I be okay just running the model as is?

Comment: You can compute the results with several different cov_types and compare. If the within cluster correlation is not negligible, e.g. because there is a random intercept effect, then non-robust or only HC standard errors will be incorrect. In that case cluster correlation has to be taken into account for inference. The recommendation in the literature to get good results with cluster robust standard errors is to have at least 50 or 60 clusters (AFAIR). So, it will not be a problem with your sample size.

Comment: Got it, thanks! How would I know if there is a random intercept effect?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that literature, I don't know how we would test whether there is a random effect in the model that causes intra-cluster correlation. If you really want to know, ask on stats.stackexchange without being python/statsmodels specific.